# Disable share (email, message, airdrop) on Finder and Safari

Tags: finder, safari, sharing, contextual-menu

Finder has the option to share via email, message or airdrop is you right-click/(control-click) on a file as one can see in the image below, [image: Finder control-click share menu]

I don't need this feature and I wouldn't mind if it weren't for the fact that if you accidentally pass over the said option, I get the beach ball for a random interval of time ranging from 5-60 seconds.

A similar event also happens when I click on Safari's Share menu.

[image: Safari Share menu]

Granted that one can use keyboard shortcuts to avoid control-click altogether, but I prefer the mouse.

I have already turned off all contextual services in keyboard preferences and pored over the safari and finder .plist files to no result.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Without installing third party apps please!

Operating system: Mountain Lion 10.8.5
Programs installed: fresh install (a month old) + libreoffice, Dupeguru, VLC, qbittorent, synctwofolders, cool-term, DJview.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  You might want to split this in two. My guess is the steps to change safari are not the steps to change the share contextual menu pop up.

Comment: I didn't split the question as they both seem to trigger a similar type of contextual service in the background. On further verification, the problem is replicated on all apple apps with a share menu. If you could tell me how to find the contextual service in question, maybe there is a way to stop it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

But you can do away with the buttons at some places at least:

Anywhere you see the "share-button" you can command-drag it out of the toolbar and it will disappear.

Also you can disable parts of it it via your system preferences:

Click on the "extensions" pane

[image]

Then disable the sharing services you don't want by unchecking their checkmark:

[image]

Lastly, there's the extension in the "today"-section of notification center.

You can easily delete it there by clicking on "Edit" and then clicking the red delete icon.

[image]
[image]